# Figma to React component through CI/CD pipeline

Tags: reactjs, cicd, figma, figma-api, figma-plugin

We're using Material UI to build components. it does not matter whether your answer uses GitHub actin or any other CI/CD tool.

Figma has many plugins available to export as a react component. then we can use these exported code anywhere in project. so there are manual processes involve.

My requirement is to connect figma with GitHub so any changes in figma push to GitHub and based on that I can run CI/CD pipeline.

This CI/CD pipeline generate a react component and add these component into my re-usable UI library GitHub repo. Here one thing to notice is re-usable UI library repo is separate from one that will connect with figma.

my purpose to integrate CI/CD pipeline with figma changes is to eliminate manual processes. and as a team we've all figma component as a re-usable react component and we can use it in other internal projects without focusing much time and effort on creating re-usable react components.

Next question is in CI/CD pipeline how we can generate react component from figma design? As I mention above, there are many plugins available that export react component from figma but I want to achieve this process by CI/CD pipeline. I need component that generate through CI/CD is build on top of Material UI react library so I or team member don't have t manually update component with Material UI.

If you can answer in detailed steps that would be very nice of you. However if you highlight the overall process, different plugins, steps that would be fine as well.